# How to avoid useRef when the parent wants the child to do something?

Tags: reactjs

**My Problem**

[image]

I have a stepper (parent component) to create a product. Depending on `activeStep`, I render a different child. Currently I have children which are forms and children which handle file uploads. My parent component needs to interact with the children in the following way:

- When clicking `NEXT` on parent, the child should do some final tasks (e.g. submitting the form) and then tell the parent if it succeded. On success, the parent's `activeStep` is incremented and the next step is rendered.

**Dirty Solution**

A easy way to do this would be holding a ref to the current child and each child has the following properties

- `doFinalTasks = () => Promise<boolean>`
- `nextDisabled: boolean`

**Since useRef should be avoided if possible I have thought of different options but they all seem unnecessarily complicated**

**Other solutions**

No children - everything in one file

- Ugh... maybe if I only had two steps. That would also make it harder to change steps in the future.

Redux

- I don't see a reason the information inside the children should be exposed in a global store just for this one task.

Callbacks / Events

- Event to tell child to `doFinalTasks` and event to tell parent it has finished. How can I pass an event to my child?

React.useReducer

- Again it's easy to let a child tell the parent what to do my providing the action inside the property which the child can call but how to tell the child to do final tasks before rendering the step?

**Or maybe all this needs to be structured completely different?**

Comment: You could lift up the state from the children to the parent and do the "final tasks" in the parent instead when Next is clicked, since the parent knows when Next is clicked.

Comment: With lift up you mean moving the code from child to parent? Problem is that every children has a slightly different final tasks. Also final tasks include submitting the form. If I move that code to the parent I still need a ref to the form in the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was talking to a react developer today and he also suggested that the react way to do this would be to lift up the state just as @cbr suggested.

What that means is letting the parent component handle the state which is im my case the forms and corresponding actions submitting / fileuploading. The children only takes care of styling. This would inevitable blow up the parent component but reduces a lot of complexity.

Lifting State Up from react docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html